# Add new column describing unique values per ID

Tags: r

The data I have contain four fields: `ID`, `x1` (numeric), `x2` (numeric), and `x3` (factor). Some IDs have multiple records, and also some values of `x3` are missing (`NA`). Here is a sample

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6)
x1 <- rnorm(16,0,1)
x2 <- rnorm(16,2,2)
x3 <- c("a", "a", "a", NA, "b", "b", "c", "c", "a", "c", "w", "w", "w", "y", NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(ID, x1, x2, x3)
```

I want to to create a new field (let's call it `unqind`) to check whether each `ID` has unique values of `x3`.

For example, `ID=1` has four observations of `x3` (`"a", "a", "a", NA`) ... three "a"'s and one `NA`. Therefore `unqind=0`.

`ID=2` has two observations of `x3` (2 "b"s)... therefore, `unqind=1`.

In case all values of `x3` are `NA`s per ID, then `unqind=1`.

After creating `unqind`, `df` looks like:

```
ID          x1           x2  x3 unqind
 1   0.9087691    4.4353865   a      0
 1   0.3686852    2.5851186   a      0
 1   -1.335171      1.18109   a      0
 1  -0.1596629     0.593775  NA      0
 2   0.4841148    0.1684549   b      1
 2   0.1256352    4.2785666   b      1
 3   -0.954508    3.1284599   c      0
 3   0.3502183    2.4766285   c      0
 3  -1.2365438     1.041901   a      0
 3   0.9786498   -0.6517521   c      0
 4   1.3426399    1.5733424   w      1
 4  -0.3117586   -0.4648479   w      1
 4    0.136769   -2.6124866   w      1
 5  -1.3295984    6.2783164   y      1
 6  -1.1989125   -1.7025381  NA      1
 6  -0.8936165    2.3131387  NA      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this quite easily with the *data.table* package.  `uniqueN()` is equivalent to `length(unique(x))` but much faster.  Group by ID and compare the result to 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, unqind := as.integer(uniqueN(x3) == 1L), by = ID]
```

Another option, using base R, could be with `ave()`.

```
df$unqind <- with(df, {
  as.integer(ave(as.character(x3), ID, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1L)
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Richard Scriven !